# Paragraph with separate divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to shuffle a paragraph. I would like the paragraph to appear in a block, like this:

```
WORD WORD WORD WORD
WORD WORD WORD WORD
WORD WORD WORD WORD
WORD WORD WORD WORD
```

Rather than a line like this:

```
WORD
WORD
WORD
WORD
WORD
WORD
WORD
```

Comment: You need give your divs "float: left;" and in case they take max width you might need to add a width to them.

Answer (score 6):

DIVs by default use `display: block` which separates them into individual lines.

Instead of DIV's why don't you use spans? You should be able to get the same effect and spans are not display block by default.

Comment: Agreed re: `span` being the inline analog for `div`, but I'd add that in this specific example, it looks like the content in question is a list. If so, what the OP should be using there is `ul`/`li` (which will require setting `display: inline` explicitly).

Comment: @Kennysmoothx and others - thank you guys for the response. This fixes the problem of display however it seems that the shuffle jquery is not responsive? I am putting my spans inside my div class like so:<div class = "headline1">
 <span class = "headline1spa">
    <b><a href="file:///Users/Nick/Documents/Work/Website/Article%201.html"><span><b>EMERGENCY</b></span> <span><b>COMMONS</b></span>
 <span><b>OCCUPY</b></span> <span><b>HONG KONG</b></span> 
    <span><b>ESCALTES</b></span> <span><b>CLASH</b></span>
    </a>
    </span>
    </div>

Comment: Your problem is that ".headline1" (The div) only has one child. A single span.

So if you want to use the code exactly how you have it now change the parent to be var parent = $(".headline1spa")

Edit: Or rather that wont work either you have to make the <a> your parent.

Use var parent = $(".headline1spa a")